# How can in TensorFlow use best model for saving the next best models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, checkpoint

I use keras to train a deep model. Because of my situation I must stop the training fuzee and start it again. I use callbacks to save the last and best checkpoint in my model. this is how I define them:

```py
# best model check point 
checkpoint_path_best = f"best.hdf5"
modelcheckpoint_best = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path_best, 
                                  monitor='val_loss', 
                                  save_best_only=True, 
                                  mode='min')
# last model check point 
checkpoint_path_last = f"last.hdf5"
modelcheckpoint_last = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path_last,                                  
                                  save_best_only=False)
```

In the next run I load last checkpoint and resume the train. The problem is that it when saving the best.
I don't know how must pass the saved best to it that assume it in job.

Also in new run it start epoch from zero, that affect in learning rete. How can control this?

Because I have storage problem I cant save all the best.

Comment: Looks you might need a custom callback to do checkpoints (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback). In the examples there is a callback that retrieves the learning rate from the backend `lr = float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)`

Comment: Use `model.load_weights(file_location)` before using the `fit` method. Also the `fit` method has an argument named `initial_epoch` and you can pass the last epoch number to it to start from there.